# a little or a few with 'more'

Tags: determiners

I have a doubt  on this sentence: "There are a little more than fifty branches of this bank."
The doubt is because of 'a little' that I am using with a countable noun. I feel it has to be: There are a fewer more than fifty branches of this bank.
Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is awkward. Your second sentence is wrong.

To answer your question one has to make a distinction between grammar and idiom. A sentence can be perfectly grammatical and not at all idiomatic. In fact, it can be quite meaningless.

Idiomatically, we seldom use **little more** when we are referring to numbers. We use it generally when we are referring to uncountable amounts:

> Just a little more sugar please,
>
> The dogs' bowls need a little more water.
>
> You need to show a little more effort.

If we were talking about the number of bank branches, we would probably say:

> The bank has just over fifty branches

or, possibly

> The bank has a few more than fifty branches

(Not **fewer more**)

So while it would be perfectly idiomatic to talk about **just a little more money** it would sound strange to refer to **just a little more coins**.

To be safe, use **a few more** when numbers or countable objects are involved and a **little more** when they are not.

Comment: @JasonBassford I should be interested in any examples, particularly from literature.

Comment: @JasonBassford Fair enough - as popular idiom! But OP was using **little/fewer more than** and not **little over** - or my suggested **just over**. I think that my advice to the OP would still hold.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ronald's answer in general, but not with its statement about which sentence is more awkward.

First of all, I think that the question has a typo. The title of the question is "a little or a few with 'more'," so I suspect that the use of "fewer" in the body of the question was just a mistake.

The real question is, which of the following sentences is correct?

> There are a little more than fifty branches of this bank.
>   There are a few more than fifty branches of this bank.

I believe that both are "correct," in that both are understandable and not obviously ungrammatical. So, it's just a matter of which is more common (or less awkward).

I agree that, in general, **a little** is used with uncountable amounts, while **a few** is used with countable amounts.

Consider these two sentences:

> I have a little more marbles than you.
>   I have a few more marbles than you.

Here, I would choose **a few**. Which follows the "countable rule."

But this changes when using a different sentence construction that involves a a specific number:

> I have a little over fifty marbles.
>   I have a few over fifty marbles.

This time, I would choose **a little** as the more natural of the two, *despite* the fact that we still have a countable number.

Why should this make a difference? Because of how we're used to using the word **over** with a number. We simply say *a little* ***over*** *x* rather than *a few* ***over*** *x*.

If I look at it logically, it doesn't necessarily make sense. However, it's still common usage.

(Note that, idiomatically, we could say either *Oops! I went* ***a little*** *over* or *Oops! I went* ***a few*** *over* when counting out something but *not* giving a specific number in the sentence. It's only the explicit use of a specific number with **over** that has us use **a little**.)

To summarize, we now have two common sentence constructions:

> I have **a few more** marbles than you.
>   I have **a little over** fifty marbles.

Now, let's look at the construction used in the question:

> I have a __ more than fifty marbles.

I also agree with Ronald that we would not normally use such a sentence construction. Instead, it would be more common to say *I have just over fifty marbles.* So, *a __ more than (number)* is seldom encountered.

The sentence uses **more** instead of **over**—but it also uses a specific number.

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20little%20more%20than%2C%20a%20few%20more%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20more%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20more%20than%3B%2Cc0) shows that **a little more than** is a lot more common than **a few more than**. However, in some contexts, **a few more than** would still make more sense. (As with marbles, *I have a few more than you.*)

But in the absence of a common context where one or the other form is most used, it seems to me that the phrasing around a specific number is a grey area.

Personally, I am much more used to hearing and saying *I have* ***a little*** *more than fifty* (whenever something is expressed in that exact fashion)—and *I have* ***a few*** *more than fifty* sounds awkward to me. But, obviously, the reverse is true for other people.

Which is more common statistically is very difficult for me to determine.

In the absence of anything more definitive, I would say that this comes down to a matter of personal preference. But the best advice is probably to avoid the issue altogether, and rephrase the sentence to use something like **just over** instead.